# Grails session handling in waiting thread with Hibernate and MySQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, hibernate, session, grails, concurrency

In order to realize client-side notifications in an AJAX-driven application that I am developing with Grails (and GWT), I have implemented a service method that will block until it is being signaled. I am using a monitor object to wait for a signal. Once signaled, the thread will query the database for new objects and then return the entities to the browser.

It is working perfectly fine with the memory database but not as I expect when I use the MySQL database connector. What happens: whenever I do a findAllBy... call it will only find objects that were created before the request started.

The lifecycle of my service method

- request from client
- Hibernate session is being created by Grails
- service querying database for new objects
- if there are none: wait
- incoming signal: query database for new objects (**DOES NOT GET NEW OBJECTS** when using MySQL, works fine with memory db)

The mysql query log shows all the queries as expected but the result of findAllBy... is just an empty array.

I disabled query and second level cache. Behaviour is the same no matter if data connection is pooled or not.

What am I doing wrong? Should I close the Hibernate session? Flush it? Use a transaction for my queries? Or somehow enforce the findAllBy... method to query the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but this sounds like a transaction isolation level problem where you are experiencing a phantom read.  Does your service need need to be transactional?  If not set `transactional=false` in the service.

Comment: the service itself is transactional=false but called by a service with @Transactional. I don't need transactions in the monitor service.

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but I believe @Transactional takes precedence over the transactional attribute on the service and will propagate the transaction.  You might want to try changing the isolation level to ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: the service is now running in non-transactional mode. However, it is still missing some updates. Even though it is signaled AFTER the save(flush:true) call, it will sometimes still query the database before the transaction creating the object is committed.

Comment: is there any way of determining when an entity was actually PERSISTED and COMMITTED to the database?

Comment: I interpreted your post to mean you could see the commits when you issued a query in MySQL but not through GORM via your service.  If you're not seeing the data in the database using SQL then I would rule out a bunch of more common things things first.  For instance, is the save actually working or were there errors; session flushing, etc.

Comment: I think it's really just that the select is performed between the insert and the commit of the other transaction rather than after that

Comment: That doesn't make sense if you're flushing the session though; especially if you're not seeing the results even minutes after the commit.  There wouldn't necessarily be anything in the log if the save fails due to GORM validation errors.  What happens if you wrap the save in a conditional statement if(!obj.save(flush:true)) { obj.errors { println it}} ?

Comment: Firstly, the problem only occurs when using MySQL, memory DB works alright. When using transactions, the async thread only sees objects that were created before the transaction started, even if other transactions were committed since minutes. Thus, I removed the Transactional in the async thread. Now, it doesn't see changes of uncommitted transactions, though the entities were saved using flush:true BEFORE the findBy... is executed in the async thread. The only way it works is waiting for the transaction saving the entity to commit and then using findBy.. in the async thread without Trans..al

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to flush the session on the save calls for the new objects that you are looking for, e.g.

```
DomainOfFrequentlyAddedStuff.save(flush:true)
```

Then they should be persisted to the db quickly so they will show up in your findAll() query.

Comment: I am already using save(flush:true) - I can tell from the MySQL log that the INSERT query is inserted before the SELECT query. Even after one minute, the findAllBy... method will return an empty array.

Comment: Oh well. Have you tried issuing a get() query (by id) instead? After you have looked at the db at the command line to see some newly inserted ids. Of course, this isn't a solution, but it may tell you whether it's a GORM/Hibernate dynamic finder issue.

Comment: I think it's really just that the select is performed between the insert and the commit of the other transaction rather than after that